# iOS: 13 Location Always Allow: After tapping on Open Settings, it does not redirect to App Settings page

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios13

I need to open my application settings but sometime if we have opened setting other screen as like wifi or proxy screen then it does not redirect to App's settings in iOS 13.

```
@IBAction func openPhoneSettings(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString),
        UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) else {
            return
    }

    UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, options: [:]) { (canOpen) in
        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you describe your scenario a bit better, do you have a pattern with the behaviour, or it happens always? maybe use  `openURL` instead of `canOpenURL`

Answer (score 1):

I made function for open App Setting, this work for me in all case to redirect to app setting

```
func openAppSetting()
{
   guard let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) else {return}

   if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) 
   {
      if #available(iOS 10.0, *) 
      {
          UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
                        print("Settings opened: \(success)")
                    })
      } 
      else 
      {
         UIApplication.shared.openURL(settingsUrl as URL)
      }
   } 
   else 
   {
       print("Settings not opened")
   }
}
```

I Hope this will help...!

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in my app, build for iOS 12 and later, tested on the simulator and real devices

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```